# constant for XmlType default namespace

Tags: java, annotations

[XmlType.namespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html#namespace%28%29) returns "##default" as default value.
I want use some jdk constant for "##default" String for more elegant code. 
Just do not want to write something like this

```
if ("##default".equals(type.namespace())) {
     ...
}
```

Is there any constant in JDK?

Comment: So just define your own, and refer to that...

Comment: It can change in future.

Comment: @narek.gevorgyan: If it changed, that would be breaking the documented behaviour. In other words, I think it's unlikely to change.